# Proof By Induction Quest.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

Prove that for all integers $n$ greater then $1$:

$$ 1+\frac {1}{4} +\frac {1}{9} +\cdots+\frac {1}{n^2} <2-\frac{1}{n} $$

First verify  that  $p(n)$  is  true  for  $n  =  2$ $\frac { 1 }{ 4 } <2-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }   =  0.25  <  1.5  \Longrightarrow$ True!

Second  assume  that  $p(k)$  is  true  for  all  integers  of  $k  >  1$, $p(k):  1+\frac { 1 }{ 4 } +\frac { 1 }{ 9 } +...+\frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } }   <  2-\frac { 1 }{ k }$

Third  prove  that  $p(k+1)$  is  true  for  all  integers  $k  >  1$ $$p(k+1):  1+\frac { 1 }{ 4 } +\frac { 1 }{ 9 } +...+\frac { 1 }{ { (k+1) }^{ 2 } }   <  2-\frac { 1 }{ k } +\frac { 1 }{ (k+1)^{ 2 } }$$ and  then  I  can't  continue .  Is  that  right?

Comment: In fact, $ 1+\frac { 1 }{ 4 } +\frac { 1 }{ 9 } +\cdots+\frac { 1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } }+\dots =\frac { \pi^2 }{ 6 }$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : show first that $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ to go from level $n$ to level $n+1$.

Comment: where did the 2 go ?

Comment: @Tennisman The 2 corresponds to the “initialization” step : for $n=1$, the LHS is in fact equal to the RHS.

Comment: can you see my edit please. That's my solution so far

Comment: @Tennisman You’re in the right direction, but “ for all integers $k$” should be “for some integer $k$”.

Comment: can you do the rest and explain it to me please ?